# Bitcoin - private key but forgot password, please help!

Tags: blockchain

I have private key but I forgot the password, is there anyway to get my bitcoin back.

Thanks,

Mina

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

Install a fresh copy of the wallet on a different device and during installation use the option to recover a wallet from the private key (so it doesn't generate a new one)

Don't use the existing device in case something goes wrong and makes things worse.

A more specific answer isn't possible without knowing exactly what wallet you are using.

Answer (score -1):

if your private key starts with 6 you have find the password.
or brute force it to find password.
if it doesn't start with 6 you can import to ant wallet or you can sweep it to your new coinomi wallet